# Xcode: LLVM's flag -Wunreachable-code not working?

Tags: xcode5, llvm, compiler-warnings

In light of the Apple's recent `goto fail`, I've decided to add `-Wunreachable-code` to existing LLVM flags (`-Wall` and `-Wextra`). However, the flag doesn't (seem to) work. For example, placing code after `return;` doesn't trigger the warning. Is the flag even functional (GCC supposedly removed it)? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me when:

1. I enter the flag here
   [image: warning setting]
2. Then clean project
3. I receive this warning when I do a rebuild
   [image: warning output]

Comment: Indeed it works. One should add the flag for the project, not for a (wrong) target. :) Works also under the `Other C(++) Flags` settings.